# Cannot stop the v11.0 LocalDB instance

Tags: localdb

Steps to reproduce.

List the existing instances:

```
> sqllocaldb info
v11.0
```

Stop the instance with the specified name:

```
> sqllocaldb stop "v11.0"
Stop of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following error:
The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
```

The results are contradictory. How can it exist in the first command and then not exist in the second?

Answer (score 11):

Try using

```
sqllocaldb stop v11.0
```

without quotes. It should work.

Are you using Visual Studio Tools? If not, try using it.

EDIT:
It also works if you user an admin command prompt and type: 
    cmd.exe /C sqllocaldb p "v11.0"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but since I stumbled upon it, I will add this answer in addition to Tiago Cachinho's.

The command `sqllocaldb info` will also show stopped instances. Try adding the name of the instance to get more information:

```
>sqllocaldb info v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.7001.0
Shared name:
Owner:              me
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    1/25/2020 3:40:46 PM
Instance pipe name:
```